# EmguCV CvInvoke.Rectangle {"OpenCV: connectivity == 8 || connectivity == 4"}

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I've some error in emguCV, when draw Rectangle, throws '{"OpenCV: connectivity == 8 || connectivity == 4"} 'exception.

Here is the part of my code that exception is thrown here:

```
private VectorOfRect FilterMostlyEmptyBoxes(VectorOfMat thresholds, VectorOfRect charRegions)
    {
        // Of the n thresholded images, if box 3 (for example) is empty in half (for example) of the thresholded images,
        // clear all data for every box #3.

        //const float MIN_AREA_PERCENT = 0.1;
        float MIN_CONTOUR_HEIGHT_PERCENT = Config.Instance.segmentationMinCharHeightPercent;


        int[] boxScores = new int[charRegions.Size];

        for (int i = 0; i < charRegions.Size; i++)
            boxScores[i] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < thresholds.Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < charRegions.Size; j++)
            {
                //float minArea = charRegions[j].area() * MIN_AREA_PERCENT;
                Mat tempImg = Mat.Zeros(thresholds[i].Rows, thresholds[i].Cols, thresholds[i].Depth, thresholds[i].NumberOfChannels);
                CvInvoke.Rectangle(tempImg, charRegions[j], new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), thickness: -1, lineType: LineType.Filled);
                CvInvoke.BitwiseAnd(thresholds[i], tempImg, tempImg);

                CvInvoke.Imshow("FilterMostlyEmptyBoxes", tempImg);
                CvInvoke.WaitKey();
```

in line CvInvoke.Rectangle when linetype is Filled (-1) throws '{"OpenCV: connectivity == 8 || connectivity == 4"}' exception, but when i use other types of linetype like AntiAlias, EightConnected, FourConnected i don't have any exception!
So, what was wrong here?

Comment: It tells you that `LineType.Filled` is not valid there.